# Decode Spring Boot 2.1 OAuth2 encoded JWT on Resource Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

Trying to upgrade existing resource services from Spring Boot 1.x to 2.x. Spring Security 4.5 is running on the authentication server and encodes JWT tokens like this:

```
  @Bean
  public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    converter.setSigningKey(privateKey);
    converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);
    return converter;
  }
```

A resource server upgraded to Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE throws this error:

```
OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter:165 : 
Authentication request failed: error="invalid_token",
error_description="Invalid access token:****..."
```

The log reveals that the OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter is using the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter to extract the JWT token. Spring Security auto-configuration should provide the JwtAccessTokenConverter bean instead of the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter bean since there is a key-value in my properties file:

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      resource:
        jwt:
          key-value: |
            -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
            ...
            -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Here is the Spring Security ResourceServerTokenServiceConfiguration class that should detect it. The property matches "security.oauth2.resource.jwt.key-value".

```
  public ConditionOutcome getMatchOutcome(ConditionContext context,
            AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
    ConditionMessage.Builder message = ConditionMessage
                .forCondition("OAuth JWT Condition");
    Environment environment = context.getEnvironment();
    String keyValue = environment
                .getProperty("security.oauth2.resource.jwt.key-value");
    String keyUri = environment
                .getProperty("security.oauth2.resource.jwt.key-uri");
    if (StringUtils.hasText(keyValue) || StringUtils.hasText(keyUri)) {
      return ConditionOutcome
                    .match(message.foundExactly("provided public key"));
    }
    return ConditionOutcome
                .noMatch(message.didNotFind("provided public key").atAll());
  }
```

These are the resource server security dependencies:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

This is the resource server configuration. It is essentially the same as it was with Spring Boot 1.5.x.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

  private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "my-service";

  @Override
  public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
    resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an issue with the properties. I had moved "security.oauth2" to "spring.security.oauth2." When I turned on logging for org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2 and saw this:

```
did not match due to OAuth Client ID did not find security.oauth2.client.client-id property
```

So, I decided to try moving the oauth2 properties back out from under "spring." and it was able to extract the JWT token.